How to serialize a ComputeRoutesResponse
When using the web endpoint with python requests for computing Routes with Google Cloud, https://routes.googleapis.com/directions/v2:computeRoutes, I get the response in json.
This is how I build the request with python, it allows me to work better with data received.
headers = {
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    'X-Goog-Api-Key': API_KEY,
    'X-Goog-FieldMask': 'routes.duration,routes.distanceMeters,routes.legs,routes.optimizedIntermediateWaypointIndex,geocodingResults',
}
data = {
    'origin': {
        'placeId': ORIGIN_ID
    },
    'destination': {
        'placeId': DESTINATION_ID
    },
    'intermediates': intermediates,
    'travelMode': 'DRIVE',
    'routingPreference': 'TRAFFIC_AWARE',
    'departureTime': '2024-07-06T10:00:00Z',
    'computeAlternativeRoutes': False,
    'optimizeWaypointOrder': True,
    'units': 'METRIC',
}
response = requests.post('https://routes.googleapis.com/directions/v2:computeRoutes', headers=headers, json=data, timeout=25)

I want to use the python library directly, but the response from the API comes in the form of a protobuff message and when trying to save the response as Json I get the error:
TypeError: Object of type ComputeRoutesResponse is not JSON serializable

This is how I build the request in python:
routes_client = RoutesClient()
route_response = routes_client.compute_routes(
    ComputeRoutesRequest(
        destination=Waypoint(
            address=DESTINATION_PLUS_CODE
        ),
        origin=Waypoint(
            address=ORIGIN_PLUS_CODE
        ),
        intermediates=intermediates,
        travel_mode='DRIVE',
        region_code='US',
        routing_preference='TRAFFIC_AWARE',
        departure_time=datetime.now(tz=timezone('America/Los_Angeles'))+timedelta(days=1),
        compute_alternative_routes=False,
        units='METRIC',
        optimize_waypoint_order=True,
    ),
    metadata=[("x-goog-fieldmask", ','.join(field_mask))]
)

I tried adding ("content-type", 'application/json') to the metadata but does not work either.
What could I do to serialize the result so I can save it for later processing.

What is the actual content of the response that you receive?

A Non serializable object of type ComputeRoutesResponse, which I can't convert to json and save it to serve my purpose.

The Google documentation shows that as being JSON content ComputeRoutesResponse. So you need to show us exactly what you are receiving.

@OldBoy Yes, that's the RESTAPI, as I mentioned in my question, in the first part, I already know that I can get a JSON from there. What I want to use is the Python library, and then again I'm mentioning in my question that I get a ComputeRoutesResponse which is not a JSON, but a ProtoBuf Message.

The Python Protobuf library google.protobuf.json_format includes a method MessageToJson that allows you to convert an arbitrary Protobuf message to its JSON representation.

@DazWilkin I found it earlier but was giving me AttributeError: Unknown field for ComputeRoutesResponse: DESCRIPTOR, until I found a post using the protected ._pb, now is working, either with MessageToJson or MessageToDict, however considering that is accessing a protected method sounds more like a workaround than an answer.

I investigated further.
Google Cloud Client libraries for Python use proto-plus
proto-plus includes serialization methods so you can:
route_response = ...

# NOTE: 'to_json` is a class method
ComputeRoutesResponse.to_json(route_response)

to_json does additional formatting work but is essentially:
route_response = ...

# NOTE: 'pb' is a class method
msg = ComputeRoutesResponse.pb(route_response)
j = MessageToJson(msg)
print(j)


Man you just made my day, I have been wondering why Google would make it so complicated, you just answered another question I made 2.5 years ago regarding a DocumentSnapshot.
The key was in the Message rather than the instance, ty.
The ComputeRoutesResponse itself has the DESCRIPTOR, I have been wondering where to get the DESCRIPTOR, makes a ton of sense now.

:-) I'm pleased to hear it. proto-plus is a convenient abstraction but, as we learned, it makes it a little more... involved. If you were using another language implementation (e.g. Go), you'd be able to just e.g. protojson.Marshal(computeRoutesRequest).
